# Device connection to camera evaporates

Tags: input-devices

I have been trying to write Mathematica code in a notebook to connect to a camera by USB and collect and process the images as part of an experimental apparatus. While developing the code I find that I can open the camera as a device and use it for a while -- perhaps 5 or 10 minutes, but then for no apparent reason I get a device not open error when trying to read from it. The error reports the status of the camera as not connected.

I am on MMA 12.1 and Win 7 Pro. The camera is a Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 connected by USB 3.0.

Has anyone else experienced this, or have any suggestions?

Comment: I really hate to have to say this, but Mathematica has never excelled in reliability. I would never use it for an experimental setup which has to work for an extended period of time unattended.

Comment: Thanks, @Szabolcs. I think you're right. I turned off windows option to power down USB devices, but that did not help. The only option I have found is to open the camera and set its RasterSize before ever image capture. Too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel a bit foolish. The camera device has properties, one of which is "Timeout". After no activity for timeout seconds, the device is disconnected. The default value is Automatic which is 120 seconds. The camera can be opened with "Timeout" set to Infinity:

```
cam = DeviceOpen["Camera", "Timeout" -> Infinity]
```

After this, the problem goes away.